# Authorization header on all requests including href in Angular2

Tags: angular

Is there a way to set authorization header on all requests in Angular2 including href requests on anchor elements. Extending Http or BaseRequestOptions will be ignored on href requests.

Comment: I can think of 2 ways for this to work 1. add a cookie with some token or 2. put a token in the url of the href's.

Comment: Why do you even need that?

Comment: I read there is no longer a global hook in which to configure services, and that you instead have to create your own HTTP-like service that uses the real http service but sets the header first.

Comment: I want to send user informations if a download links is clicked. With an own http service only api calls are catched. But i need also href requests.